# Unable to connect to 'openconnect' through LAN

Tags: lan, openconnect

I am trying to access 'openconnect' VPN through my WiFi and it works perfectly fine. The steps that I had followed were first "sudo /sbin/modprobe tun" and then second "sudo apt-get install openconnect". Subsequently, I had opened 'openconnect' through the command "sudo apt-get install openconnect" in terminal modes. No issues till here.

The issue now is, I am temporarily working for an organization. Inside the organization, I am using their Ethernet cable to connect to the VPN, through 'openconnect'. The net is getting connected without any issues, but I am unable to connect to 'openconnect', through LAN.

As usual, please provide me a workable solution, forum experts.

P.S.: My friends are able to connect to the 'openconnect' through their Windows machines. I'm left behind. Further, the website I'm trying to connect through VPN, gets opened in Firefox (i.e., I'm trying to connect to vpnxxx.com. The command 'sudo openconnect vpnxxx.com' isn't working, but the site vpnxxx.com is getting opened in Firefox)

With warm regards
K.N.Jayanth Krishnamoorthy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NetworkManager-openconnect`?
When NetworkManager is managing your network, openconnect and NetworkManager may conflict with each other.

install:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

Comment: Installed these tools but still facing issues connecting to ehernet.